Direct image of the structure sheaf to the product of a smooth curves
Let $C^n = \overbrace{C \times \cdots \times C}^n$ be a product of a smooth curve $C$, and $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be a symmetric group.
Let us consider the $n$-th symmetric product $\pi \colon C^n \rightarrow \mathrm{Sym}^n(C) = C^n/\mathfrak{S}_n$.
My question is, do we have a decomposition of $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{C^n}$ as a direct sum of vector bundles corresponding to the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{S}_n$? That is, I expect the decomposition
\begin{equation}
\pi_*\mathcal{O}_{C^n} = \bigoplus_{\rho \in \mathrm{Irr}(\mathrm{Rep}(\mathfrak{S}_n))} E_{\rho}^{\oplus \mathrm{dim} \rho}.
\end{equation}
This quotient map $\pi$ has a ramification locus $\Delta$, the big diagonal.
Away from $\Delta$, we have a free action. So I think we have an exact sequence
\begin{equation}
 0 \xrightarrow{\iota} \bigoplus_{\rho \in \mathrm{Irr}(\mathrm{Rep}(\mathfrak{S}_n))} E_{\rho}^{\oplus \mathrm{dim} \rho} \rightarrow \pi_*\mathcal{O}_{C^n} \rightarrow \mathrm{Coker} (\iota) \rightarrow 0.
\end{equation}
(Is it correct?)
If it is correct, we only need to show that $\mathrm{Coker} (\iota) =0$. But I don't know how to show its stalk at $x  \in \Delta$ is zero.
Thank you in advance.
